# Can I Bluetooth tether my Acer Iconia A500?

Tags: motorola-droid, 3.0-honeycomb, bluetooth-tethering

Anyone have an Acer A500 (just got mine today) and have luck with bluetooth network tethering.
I've got an OG Droid, so WiFi is not a possibility at the moment.
Tried the directions here: http://www.droid-life.com/2011/03/01/how-to-bluetooth-tether-to-motorola-xoom-using-original-droid/

but had no luck.  I realize that those are for the XOOM, but I was hoping it would be the same since they both run stock honeycomb.  I got as far as pairing the devices, but when I click on the droid device on the A500 it shows nothing under profiles, where it should show Tethering.

would really like to be able to tether with this until I get a new phone

Comment: Whilst the phone I used is an iPhone, the instructions on the link you provided were similar to the steps I followed and am now able to surf off the back of my iPhone's data-contract.  Have you checked tether is enabled on the phone?

Comment: yeah, I turned BT tethering on in android-wifi-tether (which does do BT as well)

Answer (score 1):

The user guide for A500 says bluetooth only supports mikeless head phones.  I'm, miffed too.

Comment: Meaning it doesn't support headsets with mics, or it doesn't support ANY other bluetooth operations?

Answer (score 0):

Have an A500, droid1, and here is how I got WiFi tether to work.

Root the phone, root the a500. Install RootExplorer for the a500 and http://code.google.com/p/android-wifi-tether/ for the phone.

Replace the WPA supplicant file as per these instructions: http://www.xoomforums.com/forum/motorola-xoom-hacking-guides/4016-how-enable-ad-hoc-wi-fi-connection.html (I know it's for the xoom, but I have it running on my a500 and it works fine).

Turn on the wifi (not the bluetooth) tether on the phone, and you should see it available on the a500 (given you replaced the supplicant, as above).

I know it's not Bluetooth, but the stack doesn't expose ad-hoc bluetooth networking as of this release. This was you can get SOMETHING going. Enjoy!

J3

Answer (score 0):

Try the [PDAnet Tablet app](https://market.android.com/details?id=com.pdanet.tablet), it's in beta but might work with the Acer A500.

Comment: This app is outdated (only for Android 3.x Honeycomb)